# A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property

Tags: c#, microsoft-bits, bits-service

Following is my code :

```
private BitsManager manager;
private const string DisplayName = "Test Job";       

public SyncHelper()
{
    manager = new BitsManager();
}        

BitsJob uploadBitsJob = manager.CreateJob(DisplayName, JobType.Upload);
```

I am getting following error :

`A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property 'BITSIntegrationModule.SyncService.SyncHelper.manager'`

Comment: And what part of the message do you have an issue with?

Comment: The question would have been more clear had the OP included the class declaration for `SyncHelper`.

Comment: Don't forget to *ask a question* in your question. There's no question here, just a description of some behaviour.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The line

```
BitsJob uploadBitsJob = manager.CreateJob(DisplayName, JobType.Upload);
```

can't access manager because it hasn't been set to anything yet - you could move the allocation into the constructor -

```
private readonly BitsManager manager;
private const string DisplayName = "Test Job";       
BitsJob readonly uploadBitsJob;

public SyncHelper()
{
  manager = new BitsManager();
  uploadBitsJob = manager.CreateJob(DisplayName, JobType.Upload);
}
```

Comment: I would also add readonly on uploadBitsJob to make sure it can't be changed once object is created.  If it makes sense.

Comment: Do you ask me to move `BitsJob uploadBitsJob = manager.CreateJob(DisplayName, JobType.Upload);` part into constructor as well. B'cos `manager = new BitsManager();` is already within the constructor.

Comment: I've updated with a bit more code - I meant to allocate uploadBitsJob in the constructor - it can't be initialised how you're currently doing it because manager isn't set until the constructor

Comment: @NDJ yes, moving into constructor works fine..But still I am little bit confuse about what happen, if you can explain this little more for me. thanks.

Comment: If you were setting it to say a new BitsJob, then it would be fine - BitsJob uploadBitsJob  = new BitsJob();  But, because it needs manager to be set then you need to defer the allocation until manager refers to something valid

Comment: @MadurikaWelivita - the rules of C# say that you're not allowed to access any instance methods/fields/properties when you're using a field initializer. That's what the error says. That's what you've got to avoid doing. It's tricky to know how else to say it.

Comment: @NDJ thanks, so, why is it not enough to keep only ` manager = new BitsManager();` within the constructor?

Comment: As Damien_The_Unbeliever says, because uploadBitsJob can't be instantiated with a reliance on an instance method/field/property - and to create your uploadBitsJob you need the manager instance method CreateJob.

Answer (score 3):

`uploadBitsJob` is declared at the class level which makes it a field.  Field instances can't be used to initialize other fields.

Instead, you can declare the field without initializing it:

`BitsJob uploadBitsJob;`

Then initialize the field in the constructor:

```
public SyncHelper()
{
  manager = new BitsManager();
  uploadBitsJob = manager.CreateJob(DisplayName, JobType.Upload);//here.  Now manager is initialized
}
```