# C# Error: A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property

Tags: c#

I'm going to make library managment application. but at the begining stage I have an error called,
"A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property 'ProjectRI.ClassesAndInterfaces.StudentClass.x'"

I have class called 'DbClass';

```
class DBclass
{
    private static String conString = @"server=localhost;user id=root;persistsecurityinfo=True;database=royalinstitute";

    public String ConString
    {
        get { return conString; }
        set { conString = value; }
    }
}
```

My connection string in this 'DbClass', so it can change easily and also the conString variable can use just by creating an object.. And that field is encapsulated.

I have another class called 'StudentClass';

```
class StudentClass
{
    DBclass x = new DBclass();
    MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(x.ConString);

    public void add() 
    { 
    }

    public void update()
    {
    }

    public void remove()
    {
    }
}
```

The error in this StudentClass. That is, i cannot access 'conString' field in my 'DbClass' by creating an object 'x'.

MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(x.ConString);

The error is above line, "Error 1   A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property"

Please help me to fix this..

Comment: you can't do that. you should use a constructor.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14439231/a-field-initializer-cannot-reference-the-nonstatic-field-method-or-property

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15204420/a-field-initializer-cannot-reference-the-non-static-field-method-or-property

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the property static :

```
public static String ConString
{
    get { return conString; }
    set { conString = value; }
}
```

Use it with : `MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(DBClass.ConString);`

Comment: I tried this, then it shows a new error
"Error: The name 'DbClass' does not exist in the current context"

Comment: Made a type fault. try again i updated the code

Comment: Thank you, It Worked..
but this is not the answer that i expected, i want to access encapsulated 'conString' field using 'ConString' property..

Comment: make the property static then

Comment: I'll try and tell you..

Comment: Perfect, Thank you.. Now it's working as i expected..
Thank you very much..

Answer (score 0):

```
class StudentClass
{
    DBclass x = new DBclass();
    MySqlConnection conn=  null;

    public StudentClass()
    {
        conn = new MySqlConnection(x.ConString);
    }

    public void add()
    {
    }

    public void update()
    {
    }

    public void remove()
    {
    }
}
```