# how to call a return Class method in C#?

Tags: c#, image, byte

I'm new to C#.

Basically, I'm trying to convert an image with byte type from database into a readable image format (displaying the byte as an actual Image). I've wrote the following code, but don't know how to call the class method.

```
public Image byteArrayToImage(byte[] byteArrayIn)
{
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(byteArrayIn);
    Image returnImage = Image.FromStream(ms);
    return returnImage;
}
```

And, I'm calling it like below but it has red lines under `byteArrayToImage(ImageData);`:

```
public Image Img = byteArrayToImage(ImageData);
```

Any idea how and why?

Comment: What is the error message you're getting with the red lines in visual studio?

Comment: @StevenLemmens it has no error yet because the
        public Image Img = byteArrayToImage(ImageData);
has syntax error, redlines underneath.

Comment: it want's an instance of the class you are defining `byteArrayToImage` in - but you can make it `public static Image byteArrayToImage...` and only have to write the class-name instead

Comment: Are you serious?  Well if the method is located in your current class and the class is not static you call it `this.byteArrayToImage(data)` But anyway, I guess there is a major lack of knowledge among the language you are using.

Comment: @azie it will, you will have a compiler error.  Probably *A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property*

Comment: hover over that red line and you will see the compilation error.

Comment: @Carsten you mean 
     public static Image Img = byteArrayToImage(ImageData);  ? 

it still has syntax errors

Comment: possible duplicate of [A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15204420/a-field-initializer-cannot-reference-the-non-static-field-method-or-property)

Comment: make the byteArrayToImage function static!

Answer (score 0):

You may want to mark you method as `static`

```
public class YourClass
{
    public static Image byteArrayToImage(byte[] byteArrayIn)
    {
     //Your code   
    }
}
```

Then call it this way outside of its class

```
public Image Img = YourClass.byteArrayToImage(ImageData);
```

Answer (score 0):

If your class is like this

```
public class MyClass
{
     //some variables, methods, etc.
     public Image byteArrayToImage(byte[] byteArrayIn)
     {
       MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(byteArrayIn);
       Image returnImage = Image.FromStream(ms);
       return returnImage;
     }
}
```

call it as follows,

```
public Image Img = new MyClass().byteArrayToImage(ImageData);
```

**Why?**

Because to call a non-static method of the class you need object/instance of that class.

Answer (score 0):

1. Maybe ImageData is not a byte[]
2. You are calling a non static method in a global field initializer

It should be:

```
public Image byteArrayToImage(byte[] byteArrayIn)
{
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(byteArrayIn);
    Image returnImage = Image.FromStream(ms);
    return returnImage;
}

public void MyMethod()
{
    byte[] myData = <something>
    Image Img = byteArrayToImage(myData);
}
```